# c# - xml Edit attribute in child element

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, xpath

I have the following xml file

```
<date-changer>
  <setting default="">
    <name content="first.exe"></name>
    <path content="firstFolderPath"></path>
    <date content="dateNow"></date>
  </setting>
  <setting default="">
    <name content="second.exe"></name>
    <path content="secondFolderPath"></path>
    <date content="dateNow"></date>
  </setting>
</date-changer>
```

And code to populate the xml

```
XmlDocument settXML = new XmlDocument();
            if (!File.Exists("settings.xml"))
            {
                XmlDeclaration XMLdec = settXML.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
                settXML.AppendChild(XMLdec);
                XmlElement XMLRoot = settXML.CreateElement("date-changer");
                settXML.AppendChild(XMLRoot);

                XmlElement setting = settXML.CreateElement("setting");
                XMLRoot.AppendChild(setting);                
                setting.SetAttribute("default", "");

                XmlElement name = settXML.CreateElement("name");
                setting.AppendChild(name);
                name.SetAttribute("content", nameTxt.Text);
                name.InnerText = nameTxt.Text;

                XmlElement path = settXML.CreateElement("path");
                setting.AppendChild(path);
                path.SetAttribute("content", fileLocTxt.Text);
                path.InnerText = fileLocTxt.Text;

                XmlElement date = settXML.CreateElement("date");
                setting.AppendChild(date);
                date.SetAttribute("content", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("MM - dd - yyyy"));
                date.InnerText = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("MM - dd - yyyy");

                settXML.Save("settings.xml");
                consoleLog.AppendText("Saved " + "'" + nameTxt.Text + "'");
                consoleLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

                savesBox.Items.Add(nameTxt.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                settXML.Load("settings.xml");

                string xName = "date-changer/setting/name[@content='{0}']";
                string nameAttr = nameTxt.Text;

                string xPath = "date-changer/setting/path[@content='{0}']";
                string pathAttr = fileLocTxt.Text;

                string xDate = "date-changer/setting/date[@content='{0}']";
                string dateAttr = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("MM - dd - yyyy");

                xName = String.Format(xName, nameAttr);
                XmlNode nameNode = settXML.SelectSingleNode(xName);

                xPath = String.Format(xPath, pathAttr);
                XmlNode pathNode = settXML.SelectSingleNode(xPath);

                xDate = String.Format(xDate, dateAttr);
                XmlNode dateNode = settXML.SelectSingleNode(xDate);

                if (nameNode != null)
                {
                    consoleLog.AppendText("Found File");
                    consoleLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                    pathNode.Attributes["content"].Value = fileLocTxt.Text;
                    settXML.Save("settings.xml");
                }
                else
                {
                    XmlElement setting = settXML.CreateElement("setting");
                    setting.SetAttribute("default", "");

                    XmlElement name = settXML.CreateElement("name");
                    setting.AppendChild(name);
                    name.SetAttribute("content", nameTxt.Text);
                    name.InnerText = nameTxt.Text;

                    XmlElement path = settXML.CreateElement("path");
                    setting.AppendChild(path);
                    path.SetAttribute("content", fileLocTxt.Text);
                    path.InnerText = fileLocTxt.Text;

                    XmlElement date = settXML.CreateElement("date");
                    setting.AppendChild(date);
                    date.SetAttribute("content", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("MM - dd - yyyy"));
                    date.InnerText = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("MM - dd - yyyy");

                    settXML.DocumentElement.AppendChild(setting);
                    settXML.Save("settings.xml");
                    consoleLog.AppendText("Saved " + "'" + nameTxt.Text + "'");
                    consoleLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

                    savesBox.Items.Add(nameTxt.Text);
                }
            }
```

But I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` at

```
if (nameNode != null)
{
 consoleLog.AppendText("Found File");
 consoleLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
 pathNode.Attributes["content"].Value = fileLocTxt.Text;
 settXML.Save("settings.xml");
}
```

when I edit `fileLocTxt.Text` and save the xml file.

What I want to do is edit the `path element` attribute under `name element` if `fileLocTxt.Text` changed, but only if nameTxt.text is the same as the `name element` attribute. Hope that makes sense.
ex.

```
if (nameNode.Attributes["content"].Value == nameTxt.Text)
{
 if (pathNode.Attributes["content"].Value != fileLocTxt.Text)
 {
  pathNode.Attributes["content"].Value = fileLocTxt.Text;
 }
}
```

Comment: hmm... I would go with [xml-serializing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization). The benefit: you have a POCO-equivalent to your xml. Then you can set the property in code, serialize and done. I know, serialization is said not to be OOP-compliant because of the public setters and parameterles c'tor and so.... But this is another topic :-)

Comment: @DogFoxX: So `pathNode` is `null`? What's the value of `fileLocTxt.Text` then?

Comment: Any time you get an exception where you don't expect to get one, especially a NullReferenceException, debug the program and step through execution line by line. Look at the state of each variable and figure out where your logic is failing to set a value to a non-null value where you expect an assignment should happen.

Comment: @mm8 `pathNode` returns `null` when I change `fileLocTxt.Text` to anything other than what is already saved in the xml file. For instance, when I first save the xml when `fileLocTxt.Text` equals `C:/` and I change it to `D:/`, I get the exception. But if I set `nodePath.Attributes["Content"].Value = "random text"` (not string) manually in code, no exception is thrown.

Comment: Yes, of course. You are parsing the saved file, aren't you? Why would you expect a value that's not in the file to work?

Comment: I tried multiple ways, but couldn't get it to work the way I wanted. So I took the approach I didn't want to. Everytime `fileLocTxt.Text` changes, it gives the user the option to overwrite the attribute's value. If the file that contains the attribute value does not exist, then it saves a new xml file. But what I didn't want is to bloat the user's computer with xml files. But they have complete control over this. But util I find a way to get the code to work, this atleast does the job for now